# Slide Toggle With Multiple Divs

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am trying to toggle multiple divs, specifically spGroupSubView(#) after clicking the link to the image with the id spForumToggleIcon(#). Is this possible to do in a function?

```
<div class='spListSection'>
    <div class='spGroupViewSection'>
        <a id='spForumToggleIcon1' class='spToggleButton spRight' title='Click to expand forum group' rel='nofollow' href='#'><img src='images/sp_TogglePlus.png' alt=''/></a>
        <img id='spGroupHeaderIcon1' class='spHeaderIcon spLeft' src='' alt='' />
        <div id='spGroupHeaderName1' class='spHeaderName'>Group 1</div>
        <div style='clear: both;'></div>
        <div id='spGroupSubView1' class='spSubGroupView'>
            <div class='spGroupForumSection spOdd spUnreadPosts' id='topic1'> 
            </div>
            <div class='spGroupForumSection spOdd spUnreadPosts' id='topic2'> 
            </div>
            <div class='spGroupForumSection spOdd spUnreadPosts' id='topic3'> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='spGroupViewSection'>
        <a id='spForumToggleIcon3' class='spToggleButton spRight' title='Click to expand forum group' rel='nofollow' href='#'><img src='images/sp_TogglePlus.png' alt=''/></a>
        <img id='spGroupHeaderIcon3' class='spHeaderIcon spLeft' src='' alt='' />
        <div id='spGroupHeaderName3' class='spHeaderName'>Group 2</div>
        <div style='clear: both;'></div>
        <div id='spGroupSubView3' class='spSubGroupView'>
            <div class='spGroupForumSection spOdd spUnreadPosts' id='topic4'> 
            </div>
            <div class='spGroupForumSection spOdd spUnreadPosts' id='topic5'> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='spGroupViewSection'>
        <a id='spForumToggleIcon4' class='spToggleButton spRight' title='Click to expand forum group' rel='nofollow' href='#'><img src='images/sp_TogglePlus.png' alt=''/></a>
        <img id='spGroupHeaderIcon4' class='spHeaderIcon spLeft' src='' alt='' />
        <div id='spGroupHeaderName4' class='spHeaderName'>Group 3</div>
        <div id='spGroupSubView4' class='spSubGroupView'>
            <div class='spGroupForumSection spOdd spUnreadPosts' id='topic6'> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am only able to get one div working from the research I have done, I will appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you do it by class `.spToggleButton`

Comment: I cant seem to get the class working with the individual subview div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do a slideToggle on the `.spSubGroupView` div in the same `.spGroupViewSection` as the `.spToggleButton` that is clicked.

```
$('.spToggleButton').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.spGroupViewSection').find('.spSubGroupView').slideToggle();
});
```

You can see it work here; http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4Z8mY/.

What it does is:

1. Install click handlers on `.spToggleButton` objects
2. Starting with the object that was clicked, find the nearest ancestor with a class of `spGroupViewSection`.
3. Search in that oject for an object that matches `.spSubGroupView`.
4. Then, call `.slideToggle()` on anything that matches.